# MPSImageGaussianBlur vs CIGaussianBlur vs UIBlurEffect

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

There seem to be much more than one way to blur image views in iOS

What are the pros/cons between and use cases for MPSImageGaussianBlur, CIGaussianBlur, UIBlurEffect and whichever ones I'm missing?